# SharePoint and SQL architecture

Tags: sql, sharepoint, windows-server

I'm going to be working a little in SharePoint, and for that I have to set up Windows server (to have SharePoint on) and Microsoft SQL. In SharePoint I will have a few components, for registering and reporting different things.

My question, how would a simple architecure look like for this, or maybe a deployment diagram?
I tried to research this, but it all looks so complicated, I am just starting out, and don't know much about what protocols are used where and stuff like that, thoughts on how the architecture could look like?

Edit: This is basically how I see it right now:

[image]

Comment: You can install Sharepoint on multiple server, on each installation you can choose to install a subset of components or service (like search, front-end),also the database can be installed on separate machine, all of this is made for performance reason. If you plan your Sharepoint for mission critical application (many clients, large lists, big files, etc), then install service and components on different machines, otherwise install sharepoint (with all service on single machine and Sql Server into another machine) this is the common scenario.

Comment: Yes, so that would look something like I have done it? SharePoint and all its services on one machine, and then the sql server on another? What protocol is used between the two, http?

Comment: One of SQL Server protocol, generally TCP or namedPipe depending on how you have configured the SQL Server and which version you have [See this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx). Check the SQL Server configuration.

Comment: Oh, okey! Helps alot actually